# To order null values in createcritera.list

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a problem when sorting a list created using createCriteria.
The problem is when I sort according to some a property its value is null , then the whole object is excluded from the list.
(the sort parameter is passed through sorttable column )

Here is a sample of my code.

```
SomeClass.createCriteria().list {
 eq('sth', sth)
if (sort == 'someValue') {
                  nestedClass1 {
                   nestedClass2 {
                    nestedClass3 {
                       order('name', sortOrder)
                              } } }
                        }}
```

The problem is for instance when nestedCalss1 is null then the whole object is dropped from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Association queries like that are inner joins by default, to include nulls you need to use left outer joins, which you can do with `createAlias`

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification

SomeClass.createCriteria().list {
  eq('sth', sth)
  if (sort == 'someValue') {
    createAlias("nestedClass1", "nc1", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    createAlias("nc1.nestedClass2", "nc2", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    createAlias("nc2.nestedClass3", "nc3", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    order("nc3.name", sortOrder)
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked thnx very much! but how can i make the nulls last in the order of my list as they appear now on the top of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can make the nulls last in the order of the list:

```
def c = SomeClass.createCriteria()
List instanceList = c.list {
   eq('sth', sth)
   if (sort == 'someValue') {
       createAlias("nestedClass1", "nc1", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
       createAlias("nc1.nestedClass2", "nc2", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
       createAlias("nc2.nestedClass3", "nc3", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

       if(params.order == "asc") 
   c.addOrder(Order.asc("nc3.name").nulls(org.hibernate.NullPrecedence.LAST))
       else 
   c.addOrder(Order.desc("nc3.name").nulls(org.hibernate.NullPrecedence.LAST))
    }
}
```